# How to add a tag value to balloonTooltip in notifyIcon in C# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form application which retrieve some data from the web and show this data in a datagridview. when my form is minimized and new data have been fetched a notifyicon tooltip will be appeared in screen and alert to the user.

now I want create this feature:

when user click on the tooltip (Balloon) my form must become maximized and highlight the row which is related to that balloon. but there isn't any tag or extra info holder for balloon that determinate the row index or data identifier?

how can I customize the balloon or send a extra data to it that is accessible in balloon click event?

Comment: I found some meta data witch shown to me the NotifyIcon is sealed and there is no way to inherit from it.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add data on tag:

```
object obj = myData;
notifyIcon1.Tag = obj;
```

Add event click to notify Icon:

```
private void notifyIcon1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object obj = notifyIcon1.Tag;

    MyObject myObject = (MyObject) obj;

    ShowInTaskbar = true;
    notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

    for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; x++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["idObject"].Value.ToString() == myObject.idObject.ToString())
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[x].Selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to access to this tag value inside balloon click event. And this means i must know this balloon is assigned to which dada